# Execute code when push notification is received

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, parse-platform

I'm building an iOS app using Swift and Parse. I'm wondering if it's possible to execute code when a push notification is received. Since Parse doesn't support realtime, I'm hoping to reload the chat window when a push notification has been received. First, is this possible, and if so any pointers on how to do so in Swift? Many thanks for any assistance
.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible, see the parse docs for handling parse notification payloads: https://parse.com/docs/ios/guide#push-notifications-responding-to-the-payload

Keep in mind there if the app is running when you receive the notification you will have to handle it differently than if the app is closed.

In both cases, you can handle the payload via the app delegate to open the chat viewcontroller. You can reload the chat window in the viewdidload() of that viewcontroller.

Comment: Thanks Brian, i'm going to look through that doc. Should have started there in the first place. Thanks for the help.